# Which Algorithm does sortBy uses in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Want to know how sorting is achieved in spark. where can i find algorithm used for writing an rdd operation.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Spark uses a distributed variant of the [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort):

- Data is partitioned using `RangePartitioner` into certain number of buckets.
- Each bucket is sorted separately within in a shuffle.

Comment: Not really. The intuition of `sort` in Spark is quite different from how we normally think about `sorted` collections. Your intuition seems to be limited by how we think of `collections` in normal world. This question may give you some insights into the difference - `what do you even mean by "sorting" a distributed collection which is supposed to support parallel computation ?`. One hint... you will probably want to control the `consumers/iterators/accumulators` which comes afterward in the pipeline to consume this distributed collection in a certain way to maintain the order.

Comment: And thus it becomes a special RDD called `OrderedRDD` which takes care of ensuring that the `consumers/iterators/accumulators` further down the pipeline know to preserve this `order`. Keep in mind that RDD is actually never `sorted` as per the normal `sort` definition.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh There is no such thing as `OrderedRDD`.